# How can I run this bash script in parallel?

Tags: shell-script, performance, parallelism

**I need this to be more efficient**

Right now it takes up to 20 hrs depending on the line (these are fairly large MCS datasets).

- Split large data file into its "shots"
- Creates a list of each shot name to be used in for loop
- Loops through each shot and performs the same processes
- Appends each shot to a new data file, so that you have the same line aa before, but processed. In this case i am filtering the data repeatedly, which is why I think this can be run in parallel.

You can ignore all of the SU commands and as well as everything in the for loop, I just need to know how to run this in parallel (say 32 nodes). This is a relatively new topic for me, so an in depth explanation would be appreciated!

script:

```
#! /bin/bash    
# Split the input file into one file for each shot. NB mustclose each o/p file at the earliest opportunity otherwise it will crash!
susplit <$1 key=fldr stem=fldr_ verbose=1 close=1

# Create a list of shot files
ls fldr* > LIST

# Loop over each shot file; suppress direct wave; write to new concatenated output file
for i in `cat LIST`; do
    echo $i
    suchw key1=tstat key2=tstat a=200 < $i | suwind key=tracf min=10 max=400 tmin=0 tmax=6 | suweight a=0 | suresamp rf=4 | sustatic hdrs=1 sign=-1 | sureduce rv=1.52 | sumedian median=1 xshift=0 tshift=0 nmed=41 | suflip flip=3 | sureduce rv=1.52 | suflip flip=3 | suresamp rf=0.25 | suweight inv=1 a=0 | sustatic hdrs=1 sign=1 >> $2
done

# Tidy up files by removing single shot gathers and LIST
rm -f fldr* LIST &
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it is the `for` loop you want parallelized:

```
#! /bin/bash    
# Split the input file into one file for each shot. NB mustclose each o/p file at the earliest opportunity otherwise it will crash!
susplit <$1 key=fldr stem=fldr_ verbose=1 close=1

sucit() {
    i=$1
    echo $i
    suchw key1=tstat key2=tstat a=200 < $i | suwind key=tracf min=10 max=400 tmin=0 tmax=6 | suweight a=0 | suresamp rf=4 | sustatic hdrs=1 sign=-1 | sureduce rv=1.52 | sumedian median=1 xshift=0 tshift=0 nmed=41 | suflip flip=3 | sureduce rv=1.52 | suflip flip=3 | suresamp rf=0.25 | suweight inv=1 a=0 | sustatic hdrs=1 sign=1
}
export -f sucit

parallel sucit ::: fldr* > $2

# Tidy up files by removing single shot gathers and LIST
rm -f fldr* LIST &
```

Depending on what `susplit` does you can make it even faster. If a shot in "large_data_file" starts with `<shot>\n` and ends with `</shot>\n` then something like this may work:

```
sucpipe() {
    suchw key1=tstat key2=tstat a=200 | suwind key=tracf min=10 max=400 tmin=0 tmax=6 | suweight a=0 | suresamp rf=4 | sustatic hdrs=1 sign=-1 | sureduce rv=1.52 | sumedian median=1 xshift=0 tshift=0 nmed=41 | suflip flip=3 | sureduce rv=1.52 | suflip flip=3 | suresamp rf=0.25 | suweight inv=1 a=0 | sustatic hdrs=1 sign=1
}
export -f sucpipe

parallel --block -1 --recstart '<shot>\n' --recend '</shot>\n' --pipepart -a $1 sucpipe > $2
```

It will try to split bigfile into n blocks, where n=number of cores. The splitting is done on the fly so it will not write temporary files first. Then GNU Parallel will pass each block to a sucpipe.

If bigfile is binary (i.e. not text) with a header of 3200 bytes and a recordlength of 1000 bytes, then this might work:

```
parallel -a bigfile  --pipepart --recend '' --block 1000 --header '.{3200}' ...
```

For more details walk through the tutorial: `man parallel_tutorial` Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Sweet, I will give this a shot and let you know how it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, susplit creates a separate file for each shot, which is a collection of traces (data) that have a header value of that same shot number. These files are only used to create a list to run the for loop, and are deleted later.

Comment: @acquisto2 If you update your question with two example shots from bigfile, it may be easier to show what the second solution should look like.

Comment: @acquisto2 GNU Parallel can handle your 32 nodes. Read about `--sshlogin` in the man page or give some more information. Your `echo $i` looks like you want to monitor how it's going and you can use `--eta`or `--joblog` (with `tail -f`) for that.

Comment: I guess I should have specified, but I am not running GNU. Our server is Unix and does not have the commands above...

Comment: Are you able to use plink for your Unix flavor ?

Comment: Okay sorry for the confusion, but I have checked and we are running GNU/Linux, but I guess we do not have GNU Parallel. I will have to talk to my undergraduate advisor and tech assistant to figure things out on my end and will get back to testing the above answer ASAP.

Comment: Please read http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html and see if that solves the problem of missing GNU Parallel